# Help in setting up and solving a transportation / traffic problem

Tags: monte-carlo, transportation

[Traffic light synchronization](http://ops.fhwa.dot.gov/publications/fhwahop08024/chapter6.htm) nowadays is not a tedious project, Image:

[image]

For a personal research project I'm trying to build a statistical model to solve such problems in two and higher dimensions.

I would like to synchronize `x` 4 legged (approaches) intersections such that:

- The intersections are all located within the same area in a grid type format. I'd like to think of this as a 1/0 matrix, where 1 indicates a signalized intersection and 0 doesn't:

  **Matrix Example**

  [1 1 1 1]

  [0 1 0 1]

  [1 1 1 1]

  This assumes that all nodes are connected in a vertical or horizontal but not diagonal manner and that they could have a direction of either one or two way.
- Each Intersection has a traffic light on each approach
- The allowable movements per leg are left, right, and Through (lrt) and no U-Turns
- Each Leg can be one lane, i.e. one lane that allows for lrt or approaches can have combined, through and right (1 lane), and left (1 lane, or dedicated such as alpha left lanes, beta through lanes, and gamma right lanes. Some intersections should allow for restricted or no movement, as in an intersection could be setup as "no-left turns allowed"
- Each lane should have a distinct vehicle flow (vehicles / minutes (Time)) per movement, so a two lane (left + through, and right) approach could have the following movement:

  Left + Through lane: 10 vehicles / minute (through) and 5 vehicles per minute turning left

  Right lane: 15 vehicles per minute
- Assume green cycle time (time from beginning of green to beginning second green to depend on the vehicle volumes, yet could only be between t1 and t2 seconds. Green time = red time + yellow time). Yellow time should be assumed as a constant either 1, 2, or 3 seconds (depending on the jurisdiction). if pedestrian crossing is warranted, the red time should be assumed to be "white go ped: 4 seconds x lane" + "blinking ped: 4 seconds x lane". remember that the number of lanes would be from the opposing approaches combined.
- The system should optimize green time so that maximum flow is passed through the system at all intersections depending no the existing volumes **and** on historical values.
- Although there are historical data on the number of vehicles that enter the green network, I assume it is best to use a Monte Carlo simulation to simulate vehicle entry into the system and then calibrated to historical data.
- The end result should be an equation or system of equations that will give you the green time for each intersection depending on volumes and what to expect from the other intersections.

I know this might not be the clearest question, but I'm happy to answer any questions and or comments.

Comment: I'm having trouble following the question. It might help  a little if each opening parenthesis was matched by a corresponding closing parenthesis. Also are the vehicle flow rates for each lane averages? If not how do you allow for overtaking within a lane? Cycle speeds and times depend on the cyclist.

Comment: @onestop - In Traffic engineering, flow rates in this context could be considered as a snapshot. Let's say we're interested in finding the number of vehicles queued at an intersection every five minutes. You Look at the intersection, jot down the number of vehicles queued in the intersection, then you close your eyes for five minutes, open them up and count the vehicles again

Comment: @dassouki It's an interesting question, but seems to have little to do with statistics or data analysis.  Unfortunately, I don't think there's an SE site on optimization (yet).  If you were to couch this problem in just the right way you might get helpful replies on the [TCS site](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @whuber - As a moderator can you migrate the question?

Comment: @dassouki Yes, I can, but I'm pretty sure that TCS would close it in its present form.  That site focuses on research-level questions in computing.  The trick is to restate your question at a sufficiently high level of abstraction that it will challenge the TCS users.  What you might do is post an abstract version of this question there and provide a link here for anyone who is interested in knowing how it can be applied.

Comment: @whube - Thanks, I'll try to do that. I know nothing about the field due to my background in civil and transportation engineering. Ill try to work on it today and see how that treats me.

Comment: @whuber - it might be pretty hard to turn this question into a research level TCS question. The op might have better luck if he restates the question on math.SE. I am sure some folks there know a bit about modeling.